# Android studio doesn't post to localhost, and doesn't give an error.

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

I have a basic registration script. It took me forever to get to this point, but I'm getting an "error." The app is supposed to send 3 strings of login registration to a localhost phpmyadmin. The app works fine, up to the point where it will generate a error popup message, which i programmed it to do. But it does't tell me why the registration has failed.

Here is the createsuser script. It is supposed to grab variables from the text boxes and send them over to a RegisterRequest script. It waits for a response, and either kicks the user back to the main menu or creates the retry message. it create an retry message, but no error to log.

```
public class CreateUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);
        this.setTitle("Create User");
        final EditText username1 = findViewById(R.id.Createusername);
        final EditText password1 = findViewById(R.id.CreatePassword);
        final Switch isAdmin = findViewById(R.id.isadmin);
        final Button createuser = findViewById(R.id.createuserbtn);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("com.example.northlandcaps.crisis_response")){
            isAdmin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        createuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String username = username1.getText().toString();
                final String password = password1.getText().toString();
                final String isadmin = isAdmin.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response Value: ", response);
                            if (response.equals("success")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUser.this, MainActivity.class);
                                CreateUser.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateUser.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username,password,isadmin,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CreateUser.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the registerrequest. It receives strings from CreateUser and posts them to the php script. I get no errors from this script, but there might be some

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.*.*:80/phptesting/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password,String isAdmin, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("password",password);
        params.put("isAdmin",isAdmin+"");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getparams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

And here is the register php script.

```
<?php
    $db_host = '192.168.*.*:3306';
    $db_user = 'root';
    $db_pass = '';
    $db_name = 'test';

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host,'root',$db_pass,$db_name);
    if($con){
        echo "connection successful";
    }
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
    $isAdmin ="no";
     $username="fakename";
     $password="fakepassword";
    $isAdmin = isset($_POST["isAdmin"]);
    $username = isset($_POST["username"]);
    $password = isset($_POST["password"]);
    echo $isAdmin;
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO cresidentials (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ssi',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    if(!$statement) { printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }
    echo "success";
?>
```

I appreciate all help, thanks

(Someone told me to add a Var_dump to the php script, and work backwards. (thanks riggs), so what i got as a result is this: **connection successfularray(0) {
    }
    success**

Comment: (i ran the php script by itself. It posted data to the db, but the info inserted was empty. Except for isAdmin, it was 0. When i run the emulator, it generates that retry button, but it runs the php script. So, empty data (besides the 0) is posted inside. So, it might be _POST and .put not doing anything)

Comment: Are you running this app on emulator? and why you have `*` in IP address

Comment: @UmerFarooq yes, im running on a emulator. I have the asterisk to hide my real ip address here.

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permissions to android app ?

Comment: @UmerFarooq Why does everyone ask me that? Yes, i added that in. It should be the first step in making any android app. Thanks for the advice tho

Comment: To test whether emulator is connecting to your localhost or not, try entering `http://192.168.*.*:80/phptesting/Register.php` in emulator's web browser and check what you get

Comment: @UmerFarooq it does connect. It runs the PHP script, but doesn't put anything inside of it. I can tell because it puts nothing in both username and password, and a 0 inside isAdmin. So, its running the script alright. But not giving anything

Comment: I think the issue is with script. You should first test your server side script with some REST clients like **postman** etc

Comment: I have postman, but i have no idea how to use it. The docs dont help much at all

Comment: Its very easy to use. I have once used it when i was working on similar task.

Comment: Also `isset($_POST["isAdmin"])` returns true or false not a value

Comment: @UmerFarooq I used that because i had an Undefined index problem in my php script. The only answer i was given to fix it was to use isset

Comment: @UmerFarooq i used No Auth, Content-Type application/json, and {
 "username":"fakename",
 "password":"fakepassword",
 "isAdmin":"no"
} inside of Postman POST, and it still did nothing.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST["username"])` just above `$con` object and then run postman again and see what you get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183731/discussion-between-alec-harvey-and-umer-farooq).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    $isAdmin ="no";
 $username="fakename";
 $password="fakepassword";
$isAdmin = isset($_POST["isAdmin"]);
$username = isset($_POST["username"]);
$password = isset($_POST["password"]);
echo $isAdmin;
echo $username;
echo $password;
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO cresidentials (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ssi',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
if(!$statement) { printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }
echo "success";
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST["isAdmin"]) &&  isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    $username = isset($_POST["username"]);
    $password =  isset($_POST["password"]);
    $isAdmin = isset($_POST["isAdmin"]);

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO cresidentials (username,password,isAdmin) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,'ssi',$username,$password,$isAdmin);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    if(!$statement) 
    {
         printf("Prepare failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); 
    }

    echo "success";
}
else
 echo "values not set";
```

Comment: @AlecHarvey Put `var_dump($_POST["username"])` just above `$con` object and then run postman again and see what you get